# LaTex вставка символов ↑ < ↓ в обычный текст

Tags: latex

Имеется текст  `'(↑<255)' means the signal is not ideal` его нужно вывести обычным текстом, однако символы < отображается как перевернутый знак восклицания, а ↑ вообще не отображается. В инете все инструкции идут для формул, а нужно, чтобы символ шел именно в обычном тексте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать пакет textcomp:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
    \textquotesingle(\textuparrow\textless 255)\textquotesingle
    \ means the signal is not ideal
\end{document}
```

\textquotesingle создаёт одиночную кавычку
( и ) - просто скобки
\textuparrow - стрелка вверх (\textdownarrow - вниз)
\textless - знак "меньше" (ещё бывает \textlangle - угловая левая скобка, но зрительно она хуже подходит)

---

[image: Результат]

Comment: Некоторые символы: https://books.google.ru/books?id=Kymhq2M0u1wC&pg=PA122

Comment: На \textuparrow выдал ошибку, остальные символы прошли

Comment: Заменил на $\uparrow$

Comment: @Клаус а если добавть \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, тоже ошибка выдаётся на \textuparrow?

Comment: да тоже, я уже решил вопрос, через `$\uparrow$`, либо добавлением `\renewcommand{\textuparrow}{$\uparrow$}`

Comment: @Клаус, похоже, у нас с Вами какие-то различия в версиях latex, потому что и в другом Вашем вопросе (про картинку по центру, а подпись слева) Ваш код у меня работает верно; код из моего этого ответа у меня тоже работает